# Google Maps android API, drawing polylines in a loop

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have two String arrays, `latitude` and `longitude`
I want to draw polylines on the map, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines#add_a_polyline) says, that it's as easy as pie. And it is. If I add polylines manually like this, it works:

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))
```

But the problem starts when I'm trying to loop adding polylines:

```
   rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for(int i = 0; i<latitude.length(); i++){
rectOptions.add(new LatLng(Long.getLong(latitude[i]), Long.getLong(longitude[i])));
// Log.d("coordinates", latitude[i]+"|"+longitude[i]);
    }
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` And I don't know why. I know the problem is in the `rectOptions.add()` method, because `Log.d("coordinates", latitude[i]+"|"+longitude[i]);` works fine in the same loop.

Here's the output of LogCat:

```
    01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at com.shniv.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3519)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14140)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-02 11:59:27.380: E/AndroidRuntime(25146):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?.

Comment: @Mohan, I've added the output of LogCat, but there is nothing that can help in there.

Comment: Kindly check the onClick function once(Sorry If I'm wrong). I think there is a null reference.

Comment: Are you sure that your latitude and longitude arrays are always the same length?  You are using the latitude array to test the conditions in your for loop, however it looks like you are just assuming that the same index also exists in the longitude array.  That would make sense why you are getting a null reference exception.

Comment: @artouiros, did you get the answer of looping ?